# Typescript Enum Iterator

Tags: typescript, enums, iterator

I have the following enum and try to iterate over it:

```js
export enum Values {
    name = 'true',
    fullName = 'true',
    lastName = true,
}

// This is how I am trying to iterate over it 
for (let item in Values) {
    // Here, if I use console.log(item), I get name as string,
    // so how should I access its value in enum?
}
```

Comment: As with every other object - `Values[item]` ?

Comment: when I console.log(item) I am getting 'name' as a string so not sure how to refer its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
enum Values {
     name = 'true',
     fullName = 'true',
     lastName = 'true',
}

for (let item in Values) {
  console.log(Values[item]);
}
```

Output is:

```
true
true
true
```